# How do I change the color of a cell if it has a formula in it?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having trouble with the conditional formatting of these cells.
I'd like to be able to have column "I" show up in red or green depending on if it's higher or lower than column "J".

I can't figure out how to let me do it because the cell has a formula in it instead of an absolute value. In this case you'll notice that cell I16 (the one I am trying to use conditional formatting on) has the cell value of...

=COUNTIFS(E2:E,"Carter", B2:B,"Monday")

But when the formula is performed it shows "11".

I need to figure out how to get the cell to trigger to become Red in I16 because it has a lesser value than J16.

[image]

Comment: This isn't an Excel question, you provided a screenshot of a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use 'Custom Formula is' in the dropdown, not 'greater than'.  That's how to change the format based on values in other cells in the spreadsheet.

The formula you would use would then be '=I16>J16', etc, doesn't matter that it's a formula, the conditional formatting evaluates the result.